# Android Studio failed linking references

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle-android-test-plugi

I am getting the following error in my Android Studio. This is after the recent update I did. My Android Studio version is 3.4, Gradle version is 5.5.1, plugin version is 3.4.2

**Here is the error:**

> Android resource linking failed
>
> ```
> warn: removing resource com.anirudh.gighub:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value.
>   F:\gigHub\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1437: error: resource dimen/smallTxtSize (aka com.anirudh.gighub:dimen/smallTxtSize) not found.
>   F:\gigHub\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1438: error: resource drawable/facebook_signin_btn (aka com.anirudh.gighub:drawable/facebook_signin_btn) not found.
>   error: failed linking references.****
> ```

**Here is the `build.gradle**

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anirudh.gighub"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation ` enter code here `
    'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Guys all the trouble was the android version i was using.
One of those hickups in your coding life. Creating a new project and copying all the code to that made all the difference. Cheere! ;)

Answer (score 9):

**Try this**

1) File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

2) Delete the build file under app (F:\gigHub\app\build)

3) Clean Project

4) Rebuild Project

Comment: Point (3) will itself do Point (2), so Point (2) is redundant.

Comment: @AnanthRajSingh true, but sometimes it won't clear all files and that did happened with me

Answer (score 1):

1) Check Your "dimen.xml" file and add that line (if file not found create that)

```
<dimen name="smallTxtSize">14sp</dimen>
```

2) Check your "drawable" folder "facebook_signin_btn" file was found or not? (if file not found create that)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below in Android Studio:-

> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest appcompat library. After changing to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that when i used refactor to change one of my variables in class named "rating", it changed all the android:rating attributes to android:rate and that caused this problem.
for those who have this problem, check gradle build error exactly for more information. maybe that's because of your undefined xml attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your current build.
The `compileSdkVersion` needs to be the same as `targetSdkVersion`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```